# How to emulate Edit/Update mechanism of ADO for SQLite in C++?

Tags: c++, sqlite, ado

I have a C++ application that uses ADO to talk to an Oracle database. I'm updating the application to support an offline documents. I've decided to implement SQLite for the local side.

I've implemented a wrapper around the ADO classes that will call the appropriate code. However, ADO's way of adding/editing/deleting rows is a bit difficult to implement for SQLite.

For ADO I'd write something like:

```
CADODatabase db;
CADORecordset rs( &db );
db.Open( "connection string" );
rs.Open( "select * from table1 where table1key=123" );
if (!rs.IsEOF())
{
    int value;
    rs.GetFieldValue( "field", value );
    if (value == 456)
    {
        rs.Edit();
        rs.SetFieldValue( "field", 456 );
        rs.Update();
    }
}
rs.Close();
db.Close();
```

For this simple example I realize that I could have just issued an update, but the real code is considerable more complex.

How would I get calls between the `Edit()` and `Update()` to actually update the data? My first thought is to have the `Edit()` construct a separate query and the `Update()` actually run it, but I'm not sure what fields will be changed nor what keys from the table to limit an update query to.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something (I know ADO.NET, but not really ADO), but why do you need to write your own wrappers?  Can't you use the SQLite ODBC driver (http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) and a ADO-ODBC bridge (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227219(VS.60).aspx)?

Comment: Could I use the ODBC driver without installing anything? I'm looking to be able to run off a USB drive without having to install.

Comment: Have you investigated the wrappers for C++? http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers
Several note ADO goals.

Comment: All the ones I've investigated are ADO "like", not real implementations. They implement a similar, but different, interface. Or are for ADO.Net.

Answer (score 0):

" but I'm not sure what fields will be changed nor what keys from the table to limit an update query to."

How about just selecting ROWID with the rest of the fields and then building an update based on that ?

Comment: Oops, a little late to the party :)